# Selenium can't click href

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I want to click on a href(all of the delete ones), but can't

```
<a href="#delete"><img height="16px" width="16px" src="/images/icons/trash_16.gif"></a>
```

I've tired (both delete and #delete)

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='delete']")
for item in items:
    item.click()
```

and `items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'#delete')]")`

in both situations got 
`Message: element not interactable`

Here's the div

```
<div id="permissions-advanced" class="checkbox">
            <span class="desc">User permission level is calculated by applying rules from this list, from top to bottom. <strong>The last matching rule takes precedence.</strong> Structure owner and Jira administrators always have <b>Control</b> permissions.</span>
            <ol><li>
            <div class="perm-actions">
            <a class="pea-up" href="#up"><img height="16px" width="16px" src="/images/icons/arrow_up_blue.gif"></a>
            <a class="pea-down" href="#down"><img height="16px" width="16px" src="/images/icons/arrow_down_blue.gif"></a>
            <a href="#delete"><img height="16px" width="16px" src="/images/icons/trash_16.gif"></a>
            </div>
          <span class="plevel">None</span> for 
              <b>Everyone</b>
          </li><li>
            <div class="perm-actions">
            <a class="pea-up" href="#up"><img height="16px" width="16px" src="/images/icons/arrow_up_blue.gif"></a>
            <a class="pea-down" href="#down"><img height="16px" width="16px" src="/images/icons/arrow_down_blue.gif"></a>
            <a href="#delete"><img height="16px" width="16px" src="/images/icons/trash_16.gif"></a>
            </div>
          <span class="plevel">Edit</span> for 
              <b>Everyone</b>
          </li><li>
            <div class="perm-actions">
            <a class="pea-up" href="#up"><img height="16px" width="16px" src="/images/icons/arrow_up_blue.gif"></a>
            <a class="pea-down" href="#down"><img height="16px" width="16px" src="/images/icons/arrow_down_blue.gif"></a>
            <a href="#delete"><img height="16px" width="16px" src="/images/icons/trash_16.gif"></a>
            </div>
          <span class="plevel">Edit</span> for 
              <b>Administrators</b> of <b>test</b> (Project Role)
          </li></ol>
          </div>
```

Does anyone have any suggestion how I could click that href?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the behaviour there might be two reasons:

1. The element you need to click is the `img`, not the `a` link - here I would test the locator in chrome devtools console, something like this will do the trick:

   `$$("a[href$='delete']")[0].click()`

   The `$$` stand for `document.querySelectorAll` so it returns 0-based array, since we do not care which element we click, we can test on the first one. If this does not work, you should change the selector to `("a[href$='delete'] img")` and see if it helps.
2. If the above does not solve your problem try using `Actions` class (`ActionChains` in python). Simply instead of `click` in your code first move to the element like this:

   `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).click(item).perform();`

Comment: Hi @Moro 
thanks for the suggestions 
in 1. both, the ```$$("a[href*='delete']")[0].click()``` and ```$$("a[href*='delete'] img")[0].click()``` give ```undefined``` in the console. 

Solution no.2 works.      
```
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'delete')]")
for item in items:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).click(item).perform()
```

Now I'm facing the ```Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document```

Comment: Oh yeah, I haven't notice that your css selector has a little typo, it should be `("a[href$='delete']")`, I will edit my answer. The xpath selector seems fine.

Comment: Sorry, was fighting with formatting. The previous selector deleted one item and gave the ```stale element``` error, It's the same with the new one. I probably must find_elements after every click.

Comment: Yeah, if a `click` event refreshes the elements in DOM, and since it is a remove type event it might, you will probably have to relocate the element.

Comment: thanks for the help